# Quick basic loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have the following lines in a file. Here is an example of one line:

> NM_???? chr12 - 10 110 10 110 3 10,50,100, 20,60,110,

I have the following code to get the info out:

```
fp = open(infile, 'r')
for line in fp:
     tokens = line.split()
     exonstarts = tokens[8][:-1].split(',')
     exonends = tokens[9][:-1].split(',')
```

This will give me a list like these:

```
exonstarts = [10,50,100]
exonends = [20,60,110]
```

This has 3 exons (ALTHOUGH OTHER LINES IN THE FILE MAY HAVE MORE OR LESS THAN 3, so this must work for any number of exons), and they go from:

```
 10-20
 50-60
 100-110
```

So for each number in the start list there is one in the finish list.
Which means that the first codon start at exonstarts[0] and ends at
exonends[0].  The second starts at exonstarts[1] and ends at exonends[1].
And so on.

How do I write the rest of this code so it pairs up the elements as such?

---

Update:

**From this:**

```
tokens = line.split()
exonstarts = tokens[8][:-1].split(',')
exonends = tokens[9][:-1].split(',')
zipped = list(zip(exonstarts, exonends))
```

I have another problem, I have a sting that I want these pieces of. So for example, I would want `chr_string[10:20]+chr_string[50:60]+chr_string[100:110]` Is there a way I could easily say this??

Comment: Sorry for the noob programming question. I just really need some help for the time crunch I have found myself in

Comment: No need to apologize Patrick, that's what the site is here for :)

Comment: @PatrickCampbell: In general, it's preferred that you open a new question for followups like that.

Comment: About your second question: try running that code. It should work.

Comment: Oh, I know it will work, but considering I will have a variable list of numbers and length, I cannot simply write that. I need some kind of variable or something to include in them

Comment: Ok, I am new to the forums and programming, I have added it in a new question. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want the [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function.

```
In [1]: exonstarts = [10,50,100]

In [2]: exonends = [20,60,110]

In [3]: zip(exonstarts, exonends)
Out[3]: [(10, 20), (50, 60), (100, 110)]
```

Comment: Is the zip function built in? Because when I try zip(exonstarts, exonends) all I get back is <zip object at 0x0290A8C8>

Comment: The zip function is builtin unless you overwrote it. It was added in version 2.0

Comment: In python3, I believe it returns an iterator. Try `list(zip(exonstarts, exonends))`

Comment: `zip()` returns an object in Python 3. Try `list(zip(exonstarts, exonends))` to see the contents.

Answer (score 3):

The [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) built-in is what your looking for:

```
>>> exonstarts = [10,50,100]
>>> exonends = [20,60,110]
>>> zip(exonstarts,exonends)
[(10, 20), (50, 60), (100, 110)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get these pairs using [**`zip()`**](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> for t in zip(exonstarts, exonends):
...     print('%d-%d' % t)
... 
10-20
50-60
100-110
```

---

To get a `list` by slicing `chr_string` (which I have fabricated) using these pairs:

```
>>> [chr_string[start:end] for start,end in zip(exonstarts, exonends)]
['0506070809', '2526272829', '5051525354']
```

To join these together:

```
>>> ''.join(chr_string[start:end] for start,end in zip(exonstarts, exonends))
'050607080925262728295051525354'
```

Comment: So, another problem, I have a sting that I want these pieces of. So for example, I would want chr_string[10:20]+chr_string[50:60]+chr_string[100:110] Is there a way I could easily say this??

Comment: @PatrickCampbell: It would help if you explained the *actual* problem that you are trying to solve. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem