# Adding parts of a line to make a sequence line (python)

Tags: python

I have a file with lines like this:

NM_198212  chr7  +  115926679  115935830  115927071  11593344  2  115926679,115933260, (interested in this column, these numbers are known as the exon starts)  115927221,115935830, (and this one, these are known as the exon ends)

The last two columns (the ones that are comma-separated) can have a variable amount of integers. Meaning it could have five numbers separated by a comma, or even 15.

If I had the first line of the file I would want a line that looked like this:

> > NM_198212|chr7(+):115926679-115935830|115926679-115927221,115933260-115935830 (yet this could go on based on the amount of start and ends given)

On a simpler scale:

NM_???? chr12 - 10 110 10 110 3 10,50,100, 20,60,110,

I would want the end of that info line to be 10-20,50-60,100-110

How could a code be written to make the end of the line I want to output include each of these regardless of the amount of numbers.

I have this code, that will pair all the start and ends, if that is helpful.

```
fp = (infile, 'r')
for line in fp:
   tokens = line.split()
   exonstarts = tokens[8][:-1].split(',')
   exonends = tokens[9][:-1].split(',')
   zipped = list(zip(exonstarts, exonends))
```

for the above example, zipped would be [(10, 20), (50, 60), (100, 110)]. My question is how to incorporate this into my desired info line(I have the entire expression written except for the part incorporating the start and ends.

Thus, I do not know how to get these out of the list and into the format I would like.

Comment: Check answers of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359511/pulling-parts-from-a-string-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is what you are after, but:

```
range_str = ",".join(["%s-%s" % item for item in zipped])
```

if zipped == [(10, 20), (50, 60), (100, 110)]

```
10-20,50-60,100-110
```

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact it is! Thanks!